# Auto start XAMPP version 7.1.4

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

how can I Automatically start Apache and MySql services without launch **XAMPP version 7.1.4**?

Answer (score 0):

Auto starting Apache and MySQL as a service is quite easy,just follow the following steps.
1.open XAMPP Gui as an admin.
Search for XAMPP on windows apps search area then right click on XAMPP and open it as an admin
2.To your left hand side of the XAMPP GUI,Enable Apache and MySQL services.
3.Close the Gui

and that is basically it.
So the Next time you want to use Apache and MySQL on switching ON your windows system,the two services will be already running by default.

Enjoy!